Remote SSH connection does not recognize kerberos ticket I created in the server
I executed the kinit command to generate a Kerberos ticket on my server, and it was successfully created (confirmed through the klist command).
After that, when I established an SSH connection to my server via IntelliJ, I noticed that the klist command within IntelliJ does not acknowledge the existing ticket.
I tried to make a new ticket via the IntelliJ connection, and it created a different ticket than the one created in the server itself.
I utilized the same credentials for the SSH connection as those used to access the server.
Could you assist me in resolving this issue? Thank you!

What cache path does klist show in both situations?

Two different paths located in /tmp path.
